# Is this proof on the product of $X$ OK?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

> Let $X^2$ be star $\sigma$-compact and $F$ be a closed subset in
>   $X^2$. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $F$, then there exists a
>   $\sigma$-compact subset $A$ of $X$, such that $F \subseteq
> \operatorname{St}(X \times A,\mathcal{U}).$
>
> **Definition:** A topological space $X$ is said to be star $\sigma$-compact if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a $\sigma$-compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

My Proof: It is not difficult to see that $\mathcal {U}\cup \{X^2\setminus
F\}$ is an open cover of $X^2$. By virtue of star
$\sigma$-compactness, there exists a $\sigma$-compact subset $K$ of
$X^2$, such that $\operatorname{St}(K,\mathcal{U}\cup\{X^2\setminus
F\})=X^2.$ Let $A=p(K)$, where $p$ is the projection of $X^2$ onto
the second factor. Since any continuous image of a compact set is
compact, it follows that $A$ is $\sigma$-compact. Therefore, we have
$F\subseteq \operatorname{St}(K,\mathcal{U})\subseteq
\operatorname{St}(X\times A,\mathcal{U}).$

> **Is my proof OK?** I'm not sure I am right. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems OK to me. $K \subset X \times A$ is clear, so this justifies the second inclusion of the last line, and the first is also clear as no point of $F$ is in $X^2 \setminus F$ of course, but **is** in the star w.r.t. the extended cover, so must be in the star w.r.t. the original cover.